# django-compressor Offline Generation Error

Tags: css, django, django-compressor

I am trying to compress my CSS files using django-compressor, but I keep receiving this error:

```
compressor.exceptions.OfflineGenerationError: You have offline compression enabled but key "8369f4e513fa5b733304f4b22c67ad97" is missing from offline manifest. You may need to run "python manage.py compress".
```

But, I have checked the manifest file and the key is in fact there.

I have already tried with and without `COMPRESS_OFFLINE=True` and I am not using any inline CSS.

I am not using any special Cache Backend and it is a single server setup with Django 1.7.1 and django-compressor 1.4.

My templates are setup as follows:

base.html

```
{% load compress %}



{% compress css %}
    {% block extraCSS %}
        <link href="/static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/static/css/mimir-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="/static/css/global-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endblock %}
{% endcompress %}
```

and I have a few others that use base.html as follows:

```
{% block extraCSS %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/web_user/css/adminPanel.css"/>
{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas about what I could be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out my `COMPRESS_ROOT` path was wrong. It expects an absolute path, but my `STATIC_ROOT` variable was relative for some reason. Setting `COMPRESS_ROOT` to the absolute path of `STATIC_ROOT` fixed the problem.

Comment: Awesome, this just solved a frustrating mystery for me.