# Offline Generation Error - Django compressor

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-compressor

I am trying to setup [Cabot](https://github.com/arachnys/cabot) via Flynn, which is basically like a in-house heroku.
When I deploy eveything and try to run it, i get this exception.

```
OfflineGenerationError: You have offline compression enabled but key "88dbbdf7c5e6ceca63a19023be40a840" is missing from offline manifest. You may need to run "python manage.py compress".
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786002/django-compressor-offline-generation-error) that the path for COMPRESS_ROOT might not be absolute, which could have been the problem, but when I checked, I got these in the logs. Seems absolute to me.

```
[2017-07-28T13:50:24.532104Z]    ('\n \n \n \n STATIC & CCOMPRESS ARE ', '/app/cabot/collectedstatic/', '\n \n \n \n ')
[2017-07-28T13:50:24.532943Z]    ('\n \n \n \n STATIC & CCOMPRESS URL ARE ', '/static/', '\n \n \n \n ')
```

I tried running manage.py compress during the build process and got the following errors.

When I ran manage.py compress

```
   Invalid template /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_filters/templates/django_filters/rest_framework/crispy_form.html: 'crispy_forms_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
   admin_list
   admin_modify
   admin_static
   admin_urls
   cache
   compress
   extra
   i18n
   jsonify
   l10n
   log
   polymorphic_admin_tags
   polymorphic_formset_tags
   rest_framework
   static
   staticfiles
   tz
   Invalid template /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/filters/django_filter_crispyforms.html: 'crispy_forms_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
   admin_list
   admin_modify
   admin_static
   admin_urls
   cache
   compress
   extra
   i18n
   jsonify
   l10n
   log
   polymorphic_admin_tags
   polymorphic_formset_tags
   rest_framework
   static
   staticfiles
   tz
   Found 'compress' tags in:
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/shift_list.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/statuscheck_detail.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/registration/logout.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/about.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/setup.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/statuscheckresult_detail.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/instance_list.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/instance_confirm_delete.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/statuscheck_report.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/service_list.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/instance_detail.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/plugin_settings_form.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/alertpluginuserdata_form.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/registration/login.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/statuscheck_list.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/404.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/instance_form.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/subscriptions.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/service_detail.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/base.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/statuscheck_form.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/service_confirm_delete.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/statuscheck_confirm_delete.html
   /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/service_form.html
   Compressing... CommandError: An error occurred during rendering /tmp/build/app/cabot/templates/cabotapp/shift_list.html: /bin/sh: 1: lessc: not found
```

Weird thing is , if I run it on docker on my local, it runs perfectly. I am trying to ditch the docker part here and run using the heroku like build process using the Procfile.
Not sure what the solution could be.

Comment: it says "lessc not found" in the end, so, well, maybe it didn't find lessc? :) The "Invalid template" message does not look like a critical error to me.

Answer (score 0):

Docker and Heroku would both have a different base machines. I believe you are not deploying a container on Heroku but on a VM and you are testing locally on docker. They both are different.

Assuming the package manager in both cases is `apt`, you should execute the command

```
apt list --installed
```

on both the place and see which packages are missing on heroku. That will get you and idea of the issue.

Comment: Hmm, you are correct. But I don't seem to be make the package available for  some reason.
I even tried installing using
`https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/lookfirst/heroku-buildpack-apt`
But it is not available during when the compress command runs :S , although the apt installations happen before that.

Comment: You can probably push a container too. See this link https://github.com/heroku-examples/python-miniconda